# Как сделать блок div без влияния глобальных стилей?

Tags: html, css, scss, next.js, reactjs

Есть html, которая приходит с сервера и внедряеться в страничку, где прописаны стили, которые могут повлиять на эту html. Стили нельзя изменить, так как очень много держиться на них. Но там много important и стилей по тегах. Как правильно можно внедрить данный блок, чтобы на него не влияли эти стили?

Comment: Может в ifream запихнуть? Он вроде в "своей" среде. Но не знаю, хороший ли это подход.

Comment: Интересная мысль, но iframe не то... может есть ещё какие-то идеи?

Comment: Если нет возможности произвести рефакторинг стилей с !important/привязанных к тэгам, то единственный вариант - перезаписывать существующие стили новыми !important с нужными стилями